# ASP.net core docker https on Azure App Service Containers

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

How does one get ASP.net core to run in docker on SSL that works with Azure App Service for Containers?

I have it working on HTTP, but as soon as I try and bind it to SSL so that ASP.NET's validation for things like oauth and even swagger will work properly it fails telling me that "Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found."  There is no way on the runtime only image that vs.net generates to run the development certificates and even then that would seem insecure and probably through certificate errors in the browser.

Basically I need https to work from the external endpoint all of the way through so that kestrel is doing the encryption etc. and not ngix or whatever is running on the outside proxy as it does by default.

This works fine in vs.net debug because it doesn't through any errors and just works even though it's bound to https.

Sadly the documentation only handles the most basic use cases and doesn't outline how to get a real https website working reliably with aspnet core and Azure app containers.

Comment: I think you are supposed to not handle ssl on kestrel

Comment: Ya, just found the right way buried in documentation about reverse proxies and then an obtuse support ticket.  Going to answer my own question with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After searching everywhere I was able to put together a bunch of obtuse references and come up with the solution.

Kestrel will be in HTTP mode, but will be told that it's in HTTPS mode by way of ForwardedHeaders from the reverse proxy. In the case of Azure there is a specific set that you must use. Others will require other options and may require additional setup. This documentation will help you in the generic case but doesn't have what's necessary for Azure:  [ASPNet Core Reverse Proxy and Load Balancer Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

If you're using IIS, it just works because it's built in, or you've added the UseIIS in the past versions of Core.

For Azure Web Services on a container OR base Linux you need to add the following Nuget package:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides

Once that is added in the Configure in Startup.cs as the very first thing you need to add the following:

```
var forwardOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
    RequireHeaderSymmetry = false
};

forwardOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();
forwardOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();

app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardOptions);
```

Note that without the KnownNetworks and KnownProxies Clear() it won't work.  And it won't work without RequireHeaderSymmetry = false so you need all of it.

On the ForwardedHeaders you'll want to try and avoid .All or the other option that is listed because it has a security vulnerability.

Then in application settings you need to add `WEBSITES_PORT=80`, `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80` and `ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443`.  Until all of these are in you will continue to get a slightly different error.

Note: This won't fix Swagger's validator. It has other issues because the validator is wrong. The json is still valid but the domain is different so it freaks out. The easy way to solve that is in UseSwaggerUi set options.EnableValidator(null);

```
  app.UseSwaggerUI(
        options =>
        {
            options.EnableValidator(null);                  
        });
```

Comment: it appears this has been better documented and cleaned up a bit in recent versions, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1#forward-the-scheme-for-linux-and-non-iis-reverse-proxies-1

Answer (score 2):

Adding an application setting:

```
ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED = true
```

fixed the issue for me.  I have the following ForwardedHeadersOptions:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
    KnownNetworks = { new IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.0"), 8)}
});
```

Source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/forwarded-headers-middleware-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-6/